# Rails Has_One Association Seems Illogical, Wrong Way Around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Sorry if this is obvious. I've been using Rails for a while now, but the way the has_one association works still messes with my head. It just hasn't clicked yet.

I am creating a specialized table that creates a list of companies that meet certain criteria necessary for an email mail-out, and which contains info on whether they have been emailed, and have responded to the email (or not.)

Each entry in the email_responder table links to a single company record. So it seems logical to me to say that each responder record has_one company.

However, if I add the has_one to the responder model and then use responder.company I get an error telling me that I need to have a responder_id field in the company record. Which makes no sense to me, the company knows nothing about responders. I'd expect that since the responder has one company, that there'd be a company_id in the responder record not the other way around. It seems bass ackwards.

So, obviously what I've done isn't Railsy, but other than hacking a company method into the responder model I'm not sure what to do about it. Is there another association type in Rails that I haven't discovered yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each entry in the email_responder table links to a single company
>   record. So it seems logical to me to say that each responder record
>   has_one company.

That means one company can have multiple responders.

So you need to add `company_id` column in the responders table.

And the association is like

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responders
end

class Responder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

So each record of responder has one company and one company has multiple responders.

Comment: I simply made each company_id in the email_responder model to be unique, so it's not possible for each company to have multiple responders. But I think I'm seeing the reasoning for this. Still feels a little dirty though.

Comment: @jhon, if one company can have only one responder, then you can use has_one :responder in the Company model and belongs_to :company in the Responder model and I believe you have company id in the responder table.

Comment: Thanks Bachan. It's working now and I reckon I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `belongs_to` association.

Comment: But if I add a belongs_to :responder to the company model, doesn't that require that the company record have a responder_id field too?

It just seems that both has_to and belongs_to end up with a field in a record that should have no knowledge of its parent.

Comment: No - responder belongs_to company, company has_one responder. This requires a company_id column but nothing else

Comment: Thanks Frederick. I think I've got it now.